# How to parse json data on Ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, ajax

on Ajax call, I am getting response.responseText like this

```
.

"[  
   columns :[  
      {  
         "id":"name",
         "header":"User name"
      },
      {  
         "id":"birth",
         "header":"Date of birth"
      }
   ],
   data :[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "firstname":"Adam",
         "lastname":"Smith"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "firstname":"Tom",
         "lastname":"Brown"
      },

   ]
]"
```

Now How will separate `columns` and `data` and store into two different variables?

while I am trying this code on success

```
success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
    JSON.parse(conn.responseText);
}
```

I am getting this error: **VM23977:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 8
    at JSON.parse ()**

How to resolve this.

Comment: Run it through a json validator. The problems will be immediately shown to you

Comment: Also you are using jQuery I recon which already parses JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JSON. All keys must be wrapped in double quotes, and your top level, in this case, should be an object, not an array. An array cannot have keys.

```
{
   "columns" :[  
      {  
         "id":"name",
         "header":"User name"
      },
      {  
         "id":"birth",
         "header":"Date of birth"
      }
   ],
   "data" :[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "firstname":"Adam",
         "lastname":"Smith"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "firstname":"Tom",
         "lastname":"Brown"
      }
   ]
}
```